# Interrupt boot process

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, nomodeset

I've got a Pascal nvidia card that Ubuntu doesn't understand, and instead of automatically booting into a low graphics mode it just blanks the screen. I could install Ubuntu by editing boot parameters and using nomodeset but I can't do that once it's installed. Holding down right or left shift does nothing. Is there a way I can boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: You could edit the GRUB parameters on the installation from the Live Environment. That'll make it so you can set a timeout.

Comment: Did you try disable UEFI boot mode in BIOS before installing and use normal legacy boot? It worked for me.

Comment: @BlueManCZ Not a good suggestion. 2 reasons: First, UEFI mode should be preferred whenever available (unless when dual booting and the first OS has been installed in Legacy); second, your suggestion implies that the OP has to reinstall.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Ok, but how do you explain that I always saw "low graphics warning" until I install new system in Legacy?

Comment: @BlueManCZ I was able to get it working by adjusting the grub timeout without having to use legacy boot or reinstalling. UEFI works fine for the most part, I just couldn't use the `shift` buttons to interrupt grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the boot repair tool to reinstall grub with a menu delay. This will allow you to add the nomodeset option to your kernel by pressing 'e'.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Once booted, enable the nvidia driver in the  'additional drivers' application and reboot the computer, this time without changing the boot settings.